# How to compress PNG file using sharp package?

Tags: node.js, image-processing, npm, sharp

I am trying to compress PNG files (above 1MB) using node.js sharp package.

```
var sharp = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sharp');
sharp('IMG1.png')
.png({ compressionLevel: 9, adaptiveFiltering: true, force: true })
.withMetadata()
.toFile('IMG2.png', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('done');
    }
});
```

Above code is not working properly. I have a file size around 3.5MB and I am trying to compress it around 1MB.

Comment: What does “not working properly” mean?

Comment: means It is not compressing the image, 3.5MB Image results to 3.5MB.

Comment: Maybe it can’t be compressed more? PNG is lossless

Answer (score 7):

Tried withe code you provided, it works perfectly and it also compresses image at certain extend

```
var sharp = require('sharp');
sharp('input.png')
    .png({ compressionLevel: 9, adaptiveFiltering: true, force: true })
    .withMetadata()
    .toFile('output.png', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I have attached screenshot. It will show the image size difference.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Am I missing something? The input is 3MB and output is 3MB?

Comment: @iuliu.net Perhaps he meant that the image was "compressed" for that 29 KB.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever tried to zip a bitmap/raster image you'll notice it doesn't compress well, it really only compresses the metadata.

PNGs are a lossless format, so the `quality` parameter controls the colour depth.  The default is lossless with `quality: 100` which retains the full colour depth.  When this percentage is reduced, it uses a colour `palette` and reduces the colours.

```
var sharp = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sharp');
sharp('IMG1.png')
.withMetadata() // I'm guessing set the metadata before compression?
.png({
  quality: 95, // play around with this number until you get the file size you want
  compression: 6, // this doesn't need to be set, it is by default, no need to increase compression, it will take longer to process
})
.toFile('IMG2.png', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('done');
    }
});
```